# Checking if a URL is dead or redirects, not always working

Tags: php, parsing, if-statement, url, redirect

So, I am running through a list of URLs to check if they are dead or redirected, and then logging the results. I also have some exceptions, to mark domains that redirect to places like godaddy.com or hugedomains.com as dead, as they basically are.

My issue, is that it's spotty. For example, the domains

- custommarbleproducts.com
- danielharderandsons.com

Redirect to these:

- http://danielharderandsons.com/?reqp=1&reqr=
- http://custommarbleproducts.com/?reqp=1&reqr=

I try to filter out "?reqp=1&reqr=" and it works some of the time. I can run the script and out of ten dead/redirected URLs, four will be marked dead, and then re-run and have either three or five mark as dead (and being different results, one marked dead last time might not this time), I am looking for more consistent results. Here is the funcitons:

```
function get_url_status($url) {

$cookie = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/cookie.txt";

file_put_contents($cookie, "");

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
if ($curl = curl_init()) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); // set referer on redirect
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $final_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    curl_close($ch);

    if ((strpos($final_url, "hugedomains.com") !== FALSE) ||
            (strpos($final_url, "namecheap.com") !== FALSE) ||
            (strpos($final_url, "uniregistry.com") !== FALSE) ||
            (strpos($final_url, "afternic.com") !== FALSE) ||
            (strpos($final_url, "buydomains.com") !== FALSE) ||
            (strpos($final_url, "/?nr=0") !== FALSE) ||
            (strpos($final_url, "?reqp=1&reqr=") !== FALSE) ||
            (strpos($final_url, "godaddy.com") !== FALSE)) {
        return 'dead';
    }

    if (in_array($http_code, array('404', '403', '500', '0'))) {
        return 'dead';
    } elseif (($http_code == 200) || ($url == $final_url)) {
        return 'ok';
    } elseif ($http_code > 300 || $http_code < 400) {
        return $final_url;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
  }
}

function quote_string($string) {
  $string = str_replace('"', "'", $string);
  $string = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $string);
  $string = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $string);
  $string = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $string);
  return '"' . trim($string) . '"';
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas to make this more reliable?

Comment: Sounds like you just want to strip off the querystring?  Also, don't fake your user agent string.  And, you're checking for the status code wrong... any `2xx` status code is good, not just `200`.

Comment: Is it bad practice for the agent string? Ill change the status code to be more accepting, but I'm not trying to strip it off. Just if the URL ends up including those values (as in, if the URL redirects to "godaddy.com" or includes "/?nr=0" mark it as dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps compare the domains of the original and final URLs:

```
$orig_host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$final_host = parse_url($final_url, PHP_URL_HOST);

$len = strlen($orig_host);

if (substr($final_host, 0 - $len) === $orig_host) {
    echo "$final_host ends with $orig_host";
}
```

}

Comment: Would this work much differently, than this already does?

       ' } elseif (($http_code == 200) || ($url == $final_url)) {
            return 'ok';'

Comment: Yeah since this is comparing just the hostname portion of the URLs. Under what circumstances is the final URL confirmed valid?

Comment: You're right, I missed that. This makes a big improvement, and it's grabbing a lot of the ones we were missing, thank you! However, it's not perfect. The circumstances, are that they should be marked as valid if 1) the HTTP code is alive, and 2) the final URL doesn't include any of the strpos checks above (godaddy.com / hugedomain.com etc).Your addition works great, however some sites are being flagged incorrectly like "cyancanyon.com" and "cybernetplaza.com" because they add "www" or "http://" to the start of the domain, they should be valid as long as its not one of the strings above.

Comment: So, would somehow need something like if $final_host == $orig_host except if the only difference is www or "http" / "https" was added, which would make checking all the other strings irrelevant.

Comment: I tried this: https://hastebin.com/simesokiho.php but it had the same inconsistencies. I'm not sure how to flag actual redirects, without also flagging "www" "http(s)" which should just be consisdered valid.